# Kentico Form Radio Buttons with number values not given unique IDs

Tags: forms, radio-button, kentico

When creating a form which has a radio button list where each button value starts with a number, the buttons are not given unique IDs when rendered on the front-end, which leaves only the first option selectable.

Is anybody aware of a fix for this problem? (other than specifying a value which does not begin with numbers).

An example would be a list of selectable times, where the options are:
12:00
13:00
14:00

My temporary fix has been to specify the value as a word using the 'value;label' format, e.g. 'twelve;12:00', but then the recorded data that's submitted will be "twelve" which is undesired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check the [bugtracker](https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes). There was a bug fixed in hotfix no. 75:

**Form components - 'Radio buttons' form component not working for certain numeric values**

Using numeric values that differ only in the first digit (e.g., 100, 200, 300) in the 'Radio buttons' form component's options generated input elements with identical IDs. As a result, users were unable to switch between the options. After applying the hotfix, a unique string is appended to each input's ID. The issue occurred after applying hotfix 13.0.70 or newer.

If you are using version between 13.0.70 and 74, please apply the latest hotfix.